# looking for training data for text classification

Tags: document, classification

I am looking for training data for text classification into categories like sports, finance, politics, music, etc.

Please guide to references. Hello.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a Reuters corpus by applying at [Reuters](http://trec.nist.gov/data/reuters/reuters.html)

You can also get the Technion Text Repository [TechnionRepo](http://techtc.cs.technion.ac.il/techtc300/techtc300.html#software)

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a text classfication system in real time, you would be already having a corpus of documents. One of the assumption in any Classifier is, training data & test data are similar or from the same distribution. 
If you are just exploring or building sample usecases in this area, then probably this link might be helpful to get some train data.

1. http://web.ist.utl.pt/acardoso/datasets/
2. http://disi.unitn.it/moschitti/corpora.htm